# Symfony2+Doctrine vs Rails howto retrieve data from related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am new in Symfony2, but I use Rails. I would like to do something like this in Symfony2:

```
class Manager < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :employees
end
```

and ask then the object like this:

```
m = Manager.find(1)
# Sends SQL query SELECT COUNT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE MANAGER_ID = 1
count = m.employees.count

# Sends SQL query SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE MANAGER_ID = 1
m.employees.each do |e|
    puts e.name
end
```

I have this code in Symfony2...

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="Manager")
 */
class Manager
{
    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    public $description;


   /**
    * @OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="manager")
    * @var User[]
    */
    private $employees;
}
```

How can I do implementation of these (above) functionality (which is in RoR easy made by its ORM) in Symfony2?

Thanks for help...

Myth Rush

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m = Manager.find(1)
# Sends SQL query SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE MANAGER_ID = 1
m.employees.each do |e|
    puts e.name
end
```

Seems that we are looking for Employees depending on Manager id.

Let's start with a One-To-Many, Bidirectional relation ([doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional))

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class Manager
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Employee", mappedBy="manager")
     **/
    private $employees;
    // ...

    public function __construct() {
        $this->employees = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}

/** @Entity **/
class Employee
{
    // ...
    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Manager", inversedBy="employees")
     * @JoinColumn(name="manager_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     **/
    private $manager;
    // ...
}
```

The controller

```
<?php
  // src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/ManagerController.php

  // ...
  public function showAllEmployeesForManagerAction($managerId)
  {
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Manager');

    $manager         = $repo->find(managerId);
    $employees       = $manager->getEmployees();
    // counting employees
    $employeesNumber = count($employees); // not passed to template

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Employees:list.html.twig', array(
        'manager' => $manager,
        'employees' => $employees,
    ));
  }
```

The template

```
{# src/Acme/DemoBundle/Resources/views/Employees/list.html.twig #}

{% extend '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    <h2>Employees depending on Manager {{manager.name}}</h2>
    <p>Number of employees : {{employees|length}}</p>
    <ul>
    {% for employee in employees %}
       <li>{{ employee.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this work for you.

David

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Dcotrine2 orm, it looks something like this:

```php
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Controller/ManagerController.php

// ...
public function showAllAction()
{
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Manager');
    $managers = $repo->findAll();

    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Manager:list.html.twig', array(
        'managers' => $managers,
    ));
}
```

```html
{% extend '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body -%}
    {% for manager in managers -%}
        {{ manager.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

More information can be found in [the Symfony2 doctrine docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html) and in [the templating docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html).

---

However, RoR uses Active Record to persist en read information from a database. In Symfony2 there is no 'Model'. You can use whatever you want. By default it uses Doctrine2, but [Propel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/propel.html) is included as well.

You can use your own favorite 'Model' library too. If you are looking for something like [active record in PHP](http://google.com/search?q=php+active+record) you will find lots of usefull libraries you can use.